# Create background process in C using sigset()

Tags: c, unix, process

I am making my own shell in C. This is my basic code for running a process:

```
pid_t childpid;
int status;
int ret = 0;

if (strcmp(line[0], "exit") == 0) {
    return;
}
childpid = fork();
if (childpid >= 0) {
    if (childpid == 0) {
        ret = execvp(line[0], &line[0]);
        if (ret == -1) {
            printf("ERROR\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        exit(ret);
    } else {
        waitpid(childpid, &status, 0);
        ret = WEXITSTATUS(status);
    }
} else {
    perror("fork");
    exit(-1);
}
```

Where `line` is a "string array" holding the commands to run.

Now say I want to run a background process - I have to use `sigset`. A parent doesn't wait for a backgrounded child process, right? How do I handle this without the child becoming a background process?

Comment: The parent must wait, or the child will become a zombie.  But you don't want to wait immediately; you want to present the user with a prompt.   Instead you handle SIGCHLD and call wait after the child has already terminated.

Comment: @MortalMan. Every successive parent needs to wait for their childs..I would recommend you to maintain a data-structure to store all the child pids for a parent process and then use SIGCHLD handler as @William mentioned. Moreover there is no point of writing anything in a child after `exec` family function because it will paste the new process on top of the old one.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I think if the parent dies before the child the childs are automatically delivered to `init` as parent and those child will become orphan not zombie

Comment: @MayukhSarkar Yes, if the parent terminates the children are inherited by init.  If the child terminates it becomes a zombie until its parent waits on it.

Comment: @WilliamPursell How can I do this in code? Maybe some pseudocode?

Comment: I disagree with MortalMans claim that you shouldn't write anything after exec, but what you have written is completely wrong.  If any statements execute after exec, it is because exec failed so the code there should be `perror("exec"); exit( EXIT_FAILURE);`.  There's no need for a conditional; if `execvp` (or any of the `exec` family) return, it is due to a failure.